# audio not play when app in background mode in device

Tags: ios, swift, audio, background, device

Sound does not play in device when the app goes to `background`.

It is working fine in the simulator, nut not working on a real device.

The App plays audio or streams audio/video using `AirPlay`.
It downloads the content from the network in capabilities in app & `info .plist`, but it is still not working.

I want to play an audio when the app enters `background mode`.

[image]

already enabled

App plays audio or `streams audio/video` using `AirPlay`

Answer (score 1):

AVAudioSession category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and set it active

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
    print("Playback OK")
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    print("Session is Active")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Check AVAudioSessionCategory playback if its ok and AVAudioSession is Active or not?